# Split logic input

Tags: pattern-matching, boolean-computation

I want to make a program that takes the input `p&&q->q` and then splits the input so I can create truth tables for `p`, `q`, `p&&q`, and  `p&&q->q`.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: This returns {p,q,q}

Comment: nvm, i misunderstood the question

Comment: What do you mean by truth tables for each? Should `p` and `q` always be the variables passed to `BooleanTable`? There's `BooleanVariables` which can be used as `BooleanVariables[p&&q]`.

Comment: I just want to split the input p&&q->q so i can make a booleantable for p, q, p&&q, and  p&&q->q without having to split the input up manually

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`BooleanTable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BooleanTable.html):

```
TableForm[BooleanTable[{p, q, p && q, p && q \[Implies] q}, {p, q}], 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"p", "q", "p&&q", "p&&q\[Implies]q"}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[logicSplit, $logicSplit]
    $logicSplit[a_ /; Head@a == Symbol] := Sow[a, "base"]
$logicSplit[a : (_And | _Or | _Not | _Implies)] := Sow[a, "op"]

logicSplit[a_] :=
 With[{harvest = 
    DeleteDuplicates /@ 
     Association@Last@Reap[MapAll[$logicSplit, a], _, Rule]},
  Table[
      harvest // Values // Flatten,
      {#, {True, False}} & /@ harvest["base"] // Apply[Sequence] // 
       Evaluate
      ]
     // Flatten[#, Length@harvest["base"] - 1] &
    // Prepend[harvest // Values // Flatten]
   // Grid[#, 
     Dividers -> {ConstantArray[False, Length@harvest["base"]]~Append~
        True, {False, True}}] &
  ]
```

Then you can do

```
 logicSplit[p && q \[Implies] q]
```

> [image: truth-tables]

If you don't want the truth table formatting, you can remove some of the last few postfixes in `logicSplit`.

Note that I used `\[Implies]` rather than `->`.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: @StanK I appreciate the accept, but I highly encourage you to wait ~24 hours, so that everyone has a chance to see the question and offer a (quite possibly better) solution.  You can remove the accept for now, and give it to the best answer after a bit of time has passed -- I won't be offended!